# Dates in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a date that is a string so when using KNN, without dropping the date I get an error.  However, the predictions require the next three dates so how do I change the date to be a float without corrupting the date itself?

Comment: Jupyter is a code editor. It has nothing to do with your predictions and problem with dates. You are likely using a programming language (you failed to mention one; common languages used with Jupyter are Julia, Python, R, Scala, C++, and Robot), a library or package for KNN (you did not mention one) and possibly a library/package for handling data (e.g. numpy/pandas in Python). You also likely have some code and can create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: (the above comments are to help you to edit you question so that you can get useful answers; you are very welcome here and welcome to ask questions about Jupyter too; please just take time to understand the topic and process of asking questions a little bit).